# Make a function to find the intersection of an arbitrary segment and square

Tags: java, math, graphics

I'm in the midst of developing a game engine in Java and I've run into a problem.

I'm trying to project my world space objects into view space. I have a view frustum with the imaginary apex of it defined(let's call it the "eye" of the frustum. It's simply the place the edges of the frustum would meet if the top of it was not "cut off". All the vertices of my objects are to be connected to the eye by a line segment. The place where this line intersects the small end of the frustum is the x and y coordinates of the object displayed on the screen.

My problem is determining where they intersect the small end of the frustum. I've thought about this and researched it quite a bit but I can't find any resources as to how I should do it.

The classes I have now are the following:

> `class Point`--a simple class which basically contains  x-y-z variables.I also use the Point class to represent vectors.
>
> `class Frustum`, which is basically eight points to make a shape like a squashed square.
>
> `class Triangle`, which is basically three Points. It has several methods to do things with those points.

I also have several functions which have been tested thoroughly:

> `double Distance_Between(Point p1, Point p2)`--Calculates the distance between two 3d points
>
> `Point GetNormalVector(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)`--Gets the normal vector of three coplanar points.
>
> `void NormalizeVector(Point p)`--Normalizes a vector
>
> `double GetDotProduct(Point p1, Point p2)`--Gets the Dot Product of two points.
>
> `int[] GetSharedSide(Triangle t1, Triangle t2)`--Gets the shared side of two Triangles.
>
> `void MovePointAlongVector(Point point, Point direction, float distance)`--Moves a given Point along a given vector a given amount.

It would be great if you could find the answer with the functions already present but I'd be able to add any more utility functions.

This is really important to the game engine--it could be argued that this function is THE most important one. I guess this is going to need some geometry as well as trigonometry. That would be perfect as I've recently taken both in high school!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is too broad, meaning that you are asking for too much in a single question.  It would also be better if you post the code surrounding a more specific question.

Comment: I'm basically asking for help making a function to find the intersection of a line and square. Is that really too broad? And if I had any code of this function to post I would have solved my problem :)

Comment: Your question looks better after the edit, yes this seems reasonable and I have upvoted it.

Comment: Thank you! Next time I'll remember to format my post!

Comment: It's not any quad. It's a quad parallel to the xy-plane. So just transform the line segment to view space, find the point on it in the according depth, and transform that point back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really looking at a projective transformation.

Consider the case when the eye is at the origin and the square end of the frustrum lies in the `x=1` plane. If we take the point `(x, y, z)` the points on the line from the eye to the point will have the form `(a x, a y, a z)`. Now if `a = 1/x` this gives the point `(1, y/x, z/x)`.

The easiest way round the problem is to set up a transformation library. So you can apply rotations and other transformations, represented as matrices. It's easiest to use 4 by 4 matrices as this allow translations to be represented as matrices. With this library, you can transform the scene so the eye is at the origin and the normal to the end of the frustrum is along one of the cardinal axis.

A much more complex approach would be a general segment-plane intersection. To do this calculate a normal to the plane, n, and find the distance for the plane to the origin, take `d = P . n` using the dot product. With a segment from points A to B calculate the two dot products `d1 = A . n` and `d2= B . n`. For the segment to intersect one of d1 and d2 should be greater than d and the other less than d. You can now use linear interpolation to find the point between the two. Points on the segment are given by

```
m A + (1 - m) B
```

We want the dot product of this with the normal to be `d`.

```
(m A + (1 - m) B) . n = d
m A . n + (1 - m) B . n = d
m d1 + (1 - m) d2 = d
m (d1 - d2) + d2 = d
m = (d - d2) / (d1 - d2)
```

This gives the parameter, which can then be used to find the intersection point on the segment.

Many libraries have a lerp function which can do linear interpolation.

Comment: Thank you Salix! I think this might be what I was looking for. I'll confirm it after I get home from work.